# Is it possible to know when I am on the last element in a for loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looping through a list to extract data point, but would like to know when I am on the last element (a certain function that is run in the for loop should not be run when its the last element)

```
  for(final eachLine in _blocks){
    //
    _finalString = _finalString + eachLine + '\n';
  }
```

(I don't want to add `\n`) for the very last element, so I'd like to know when I'm on the very last element if its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such way to do this with `for`-`in`/`forEach` style loop. Either use an iterator, a `for` loop with an index, or for this specific case you can use the `String.join` method:

`var _finalString = _blocks.join('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You can track the last item by knowing the length of the list.

```
final len = items.length;
int i = 0;

for(final item in items){
    i++;
    if(i == len){
        // this is the last item
    } else {
        // go on
    }
}
```